# Why recursive nested function uses more stack space

Tags: python, recursion

Does it due to the nested function needs to store more states in the stack compared with non-nested version? If it is so, what is the extra stored state?

The code is for the [Leetcode Balaned Binary Tree](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/), which uses two recursive functions.

```
# Definition for a  binary tree node
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    # @param root, a tree node
    # @return a boolean
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return True

        def getHeight(root):
            if root is None:
                return 0
            return max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1
        if abs(getHeight(root.left)-getHeight(root.right)) > 1:
            return False
        return self.isBalanced(root.left) and self.isBalanced(root.right)
```

Recursive nested function will cause the stackoverflow error when the depth of the recuisive is big.

While the following function will be ok.

```
class Solution:
    # @param root, a tree node
    # @return a boolean
    def getHeight(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        return max(self.getHeight(root.left), self.getHeight(root.right)) + 1

    def isBalanced(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return True

        if abs(self.getHeight(root.left) - self.getHeight(root.right)) > 1:
            return False
        return self.isBalanced(root.left) and self.isBalanced(root.right)
```

Comment: Essentially, with the internal nested function, python has to create a new function object (and the associated overhead) during each recursive call, and then call it. Those function objects are thus not freed until the recursion terminates. Whereas the non-nested version is simply calling the same globally-scoped function object every time.

Comment: But there is no need to create the new function object during each recursive call, the nested function is just a normal function as well. Basically, only the states within the recursive function matter, but nested function is not such kind of state, is it?

Comment: @Kamel: The internal nested function has access to local variables of the containing function. But, the global recursive function does not have that access.

Comment: Think of nested functions as multi-line lambdas. Then it should be clear that a new one will be created every time. To verify this for yourself, create a function which returns the nested function object, then compair them using ``is``. You will find that the returned nest functions will never pass an ``is`` test, meaning they are new objects every time.